# why will I get a "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
words = [ 'look', 'into', 'my', 'eyes', 'look', 'into', 'my', 'eyes', 'the', 'eyes', 'the', 'eyes', 'the', 'eyes', 'not', 'around', 'the', 'eyes',"don't", 'look', 'around', 'the', 'eyes', 'look', 'into', 'my', 'eyes', "you're", 'under']

def requirement(word):
    onelist = []
    if word in words:
        return(len(onelist.append(word)))


print(map(requirement('look'), words))
```

Error

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I want to practise the function "map". But it seems that I made a mistake when I use len().

Comment: You&#39;re calling `len` on the function `list.append`, not on `onelist`.You ned to separate the `list.append` call from the `len` call.

Comment: @Coal_ Just out of curiosity, how did you have an encoded apostrophe end up in the comment?

Comment: I have no clue, I'm on the app anyway, might be a bug :)

Comment: You're. Hmm. Weird. I'm on the Android app.

Answer (score 2):

The function `list.append()` modifies a list in place and returns `None`. So the line

```
return(len(onelist.append(word)))
```

is trying to return the length of `None`, which should obviously throw a TypeError. Try something like

```
onelist.append(word)
return(len(onelist))
```